# Redis Exception : Cannot determine a node to read

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

**I'm trying to implement Redis cache in spring boot Project. On saving the data as key- value pair. its working fine. But when i tried to fetch key values it gives me a error.**

**This is my redis configuration file.**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

import com.nsdlegov.springredis.model.SchemeMaster;

import io.lettuce.core.ReadFrom;

@Configuration
public class RedisNewConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().readFrom(ReadFrom.SLAVE).build();
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(environment.getProperty("spring.redis.master"), 6379);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig,clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,SchemeMaster> redisTemplateSchemeMaster(){

        RedisTemplate<String,SchemeMaster> template= new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(SchemeMaster.class));
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(SchemeMaster.class));
        return template;
    }

}
```

**Here value of 'spring.redis.master' comes from properties file which is 127.0.0.1 i.e. redis local server**

**This is my cachecontroller**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.nsdlegov.springredis.model.SchemeMaster;
import com.nsdlegov.springredis.repository.SchemeMasterRepository;
import com.nsdlegov.springredis.service.RedisService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value={"/Spring-New-Redis"})
public class RedisCacheController {

    @Autowired
    RedisService redisService;

    @Autowired
    SchemeMasterRepository schemeMasterRepository;

    @PostMapping("/setSchemeForCaching")
    public String setSchemeForCaching() {
        String result = null;
        try {

            result = schemeMasterRepository.setSchemeForCaching();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "Unable to add scheme Details to cache!";
            System.out.println("Unable to add scheme Details to cache!");
        }


        return result;
    }

    @PostMapping("/getPublishedScheme")
    public String getPublishedScheme() {
        List<SchemeMaster> result = null;

        String schmelist="";
        ObjectMapper omp = new ObjectMapper();
        try {

            result = schemeMasterRepository.getPublishedScheme();
            schmelist= omp.writeValueAsString(result);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return schmelist;
    }

}
```

**This is my  SchemeMasterRepository.java class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.nsdlegov.springredis.model.SchemeMaster;

@Repository
public class SchemeMasterRepository {

    @Autowired 
    EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    RedisTemplate<String, SchemeMaster> redisTemplateSchememaster;

    public List<SchemeMaster> getPublishedScheme() {

            List<SchemeMaster> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                Set<String> keys = redisTemplateSchememaster.keys("SCHEMEKEY:"+"*");   LINE1

                finalList = redisTemplateSchememaster.opsForValue().multiGet(keys);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return finalList;
        }
}
```

**Now when i called getPublishedScheme() method from SchemeMasterRepository.java class i'm getting error at LINE 1 as follows**

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Redis exception; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot determine a node to read (Known nodes: [RedisMasterSlaveNode [redisURI=RedisURI [host='127.0.0.1', port=6379], role=MASTER]]) with setting io.lettuce.core.ReadFromImpl$ReadFromSlave@6870888b
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceKeyCommands.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceKeyCommands.java:817)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceKeyCommands.keys(LettuceKeyCommands.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.keys(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.lambda$keys$13(RedisTemplate.java:883)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate$$Lambda$569/1557649314.doInRedis(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.keys(RedisTemplate.java:883)
    at com.nsdlegov.springredis.repository.SchemeMasterRepository.getPublishedScheme(SchemeMasterRepository.java:72)
    at com.nsdlegov.springredis.repository.SchemeMasterRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d789dbaa.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.nsdlegov.springredis.repository.SchemeMasterRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$69455dc9.getPublishedScheme(<generated>)
    at com.nsdlegov.springredis.controller.RedisCacheController.getPublishedScheme(RedisCacheController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Please suggest me some way to sort out the problem. I'm unable to find out why keys are not getting in code.Thank you in advance**

Comment: Hi Nitin, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You're configuring `ReadFrom.SLAVE` and you mentioned that you have a single node locally. This does not work for reading commands because the client is instructed to select a slave node for reads.

You can fix this by:

1. Either do not configure `ReadFrom`
2. Install a slave node locally and add it to your cluster.

Comment: Hi @mp911de, I have a setup where more than one slaves are slaves of different slave, which in turn has its own master. So there is an extra level in the hierarchy, will lettuce be able to work in those cases?  deos the topology always needs to be master-slave or it could be different like the one I described.